Unable to test firebase messaging on localhost
I am trying to fetch a token from firebase/messaging to use in a notification but i get "messaging/unsupported-browser" error (FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the Firebase SDK.). I've seen people running it on localhost and I've seen answers on stackoverflow saying the you can run it through HTTPS but also on localhost. But how?
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APPID,
  measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENTID,
};

const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();

const messaging = getMessaging(app);

export const generateToken = async () => {
  const token = await getToken(messaging);
  console.log(token);
};

I've tried changing the port to 80, but nothing changed (as I expected tbh). I am using nextjs^14.1.0 and firebase^10.11.0.

what internet browser are you using?

Google Chrome / Edge

So if this is indeed a https error, then you can use something like ngrok to create a https url for your local environment, its the most simple way i would say, else you need to install certificate locally.
https://ngrok.com/download
Have a look at the docs and let me know if you have any issues.
